# libGDX Import Error , Guess -Cannot Be Resolved-

Tags: libgdx

I have a problem right here. I started a libgdx project, but I cannot run for test cause of this error.

> AccessibilityDelegate cannot be resolved.

I guess it's a problem of importing because I had other errors like it, but it got fixed after importing `android.jar` but there is not import `android.view.View. AccessibilityDelegate` section in that jar.

How can I import it and fix the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is buggy. I got 'Cannot Be Resolved' or 'No class definition found' all the time. Try with cleaning all the projects, refresh them (maybe do this 1-2-3 times). If not - reset your workspace and import the project again.

I know, you will say that my answer is random, but I do this once a week :D

P.S. Don't hate if this doesn't fix the problem, I'm just guessing

Comment: yeah, it happens but it's not about that because I checked the android.jar file there aren't that classes. if I could have found a jar file to import it would solve it, guess. but I could not find for it